# Is there a standard name (template or macro) to replace ARRAY_SIZE, _countof, etc yet?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not talking about `std::array` or anything, just classic vanilla C/C++ arrays. I'm aware of the various ways `ARRAY_SIZE` / `_countof` could be implemented, I'm just wondering if they've managed to standardize a name for this yet (under `std::` I assume). If not is there a proposal for it?

Comment: After [N4280](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4280.pdf), `std::size()`.

Comment: From the date, should I assume that's in C++14?

Comment: @VoidStar N3936 is the draft corresponding to C++14, so based on the N-number i'd say it isn't.  (Searching N3936 for "size" turns up many results...)

Comment: @VoidStar No, it's going to be in the next version of the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Current workaround

<sub>**std::extent** - the size of arrays</sub>

If you are working with native arrays you can use [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) from `<type_traits>`, which is used to yield the number of elements in the *Nth* dimension of an array (defaulting to the first).

```
int a1[1024];
int a2[std::extent<decltype(a1)>::value]; // int[1024]
```

---

<sub>**A little bit of indirection** (generic solution, not just arrays)</sub>

There isn't a single name that can act as a replacement for what you are describing, but since *C++11* one can use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to get iterators for a suitable entity, and together with [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) you have a "superb" way of getting the size of something which has the suitable qualities.

```
int a1[1024];
auto n = std::distance (std::begin (a1), std::end (a1)); // 1024
```

The drawback with the above solution is that none of the three functions are *constexpr* in C++11, and even in C++14 `std::distance` is still not *constexpr* (the other two are).

This means that the solution cannot be used in contexts which require a *constant-expression*.

If you are sure you are working with an entity that provides *RandomAccessIterators*, one workaround for the workaround would be to use `std::end (e) - std::begin(e)` if a *constant-expression* is required (*C++14*).

---

---

#### Looking into the future

[N4280](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4280.pdf) proposes that we add `std::size` to the standard library, effectively being exactly what you are looking for.

```
int a1[1024];
auto n = std::size (a1);
```

If all goes as planned we will have it in *C++17*.

Comment: If you know you've got an array, why bother using `std::distance`? The point of `std::distance` is to work for any type of iterator, but if you know you have pointers (i.e. random access iterators) then just do `std::end(a1) - std::begin(a1)`. Then it doesn't matter whether `std::distance` is constexpr or not.  The over-abstraction doesn't help.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was assuming *OP* was talking about a generic solution that works with more than just arrays; this is why the answer is written the way it is.. maybe I should clarify that.

Comment: I think it's _only_ about arrays: _"I'm not talking about std::array or anything, just classic vanilla C/C++ arrays."_

Comment: I was indeed only talking about arrays, but knowing a generic solution is handy too :)